# Mustache Templates: Use fixed size position

Tags: java, mustache

Theres anyway to use fixed position in mustache?

Ex.:

```
2020010100000000 Hulk    00001 barbarbar 0001
2020010100000000 Thor    00000 foo       0001
2020010100000000 Spider-m00000 foobar    0003
```

Comment: By padding? Also depends on what you're outputting.

Comment: @DaveNewton, no. Ex.: hero name should be start at char 19 and end at 30.
If name lenght bigger than that, should trim, if smaller, empty spaces.

Comment: So padding and trimming.